In Docker are intermediary images to non-dangling images considered dangling?
i.e. I want to know if docker image prune will remove intermediary images to non-dangling images. (I would prefer not, so that I do not need to rebuild from scratch if I change something in the middle of my Dockerfile).

This was asked in this comment but not answered. I will test in a lab environment if no one has the answer.

There's a difference between an image and a layer. An image contains a set of pointers to layers. Once all the pointers to a layer are gone, the layer can be deleted by the docker engine. So if you have a tagged image with a set of layers, and run a prune that deletes other dangling images that point to the same layers, the layers themselves will continue to exist until the last image pointing to them is deleted.
For the build cache, that is handled by buildkit now, and if you build with buildx, it is in a separate location. To delete that cache, you would need to run docker buildx prune and running docker image prune would not impact that cache.
